# reducing colors with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a script to reduce the number of colors in a list by finding clusters. The problem I seem to run into is that the clusters will have different dimensions. Here is my jumping off point after the original list of 6 colors got already seperated into 3 clusters:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([
        [12, 44, 52],
        [27,  0, 71],
        [81, 99, 92]
    ])
b = numpy.array([
        [ 12,  13,  93],
        [128, 128, 128]
    ])
c = numpy.array([
        [ 57,  14, 255]
    ])
clusters = numpy.array([a,b,c])
print(numpy.min(clusters, axis=1))
```

However now the function numpy.min() starts to throw an error - I suspect it's because of the differently sized arrays.
The cluster arrays will always have the shape (x, 3) (x number of colors, 3 components). I want to get an array with the minimums of all components of the colors in one cluster (n, 3) (n is number of clusters) - so array([12, 0, 52], [12, 13, 93], [57, 14, 255]) in this case.

Is there a way to do this? As I mentioned it works as long as all clusters have multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

Since your arrays `a`, `b` and `c` don't have an equal shape, you can't put them in the same array (at least if you don't pad with some value). You could calculate the minimum first and then generate an array from these minima:

```py
numpy.array([arr.min(axis=0) for arr in (a, b, c)])
```

Which gives you:

```py
array([[ 12,   0,  52],
       [ 12,  13,  93],
       [ 57,  14, 255]])
```